# How to modify a file in Program Files with Win7 (Security Rights to a directory?)

Tags: .net, windows-installer, file-permissions

I've heard questions about bypassing this security feature of Windows 7 before, but I have *NO DESIRE* to do so.  My question is about configuring the program such that it has "access rights" to files within a particular directory.

C# Windows Forms, .NET 2010 Express

I have a program that is supposed to read, write, and edit various files, including User Profile data files.

Now, for various reasons, not all these files will exist as the program is being installed (I created an MSI installer).  Primarily, a new file is created for each user, and the users are not known at install time.
I've just switched to a Windows 7 machine, and have had a true nightmare trying to update these files at run-time.

I've been lead to believe (in various other Q/A hunts) that files installed by the MSI will be "bound to" the program, and Windows will let the program edit these files without complaint.
Since I started on Windows XP, however, I never bothered including these config files with the MSI.  I wanted to research further before re-engineering everything.

**Question 1:** Is that accurate?  I never saw it explicitly stated, or asked.  MSI installed files will get read/write permission within the program?

.

So, with that background in mind, I'd like to learn if there's a way to allow *any file* to be CRUD-ed, as long as it remains within the Application Directory as defined by the MSI file.
I'm willing to define special "permission" directories, or whatever else is required.

The other (stupid-simple) solution is to install the program outside of the Program Files directory, but that seems unwise.

**Question 2:** How can a program's access rights be configured to allow file CRUD, even if limited to a particular directory?

.

Thanks for sharing any insight!   ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: No that is not correct. There's nothing special about a file installed by MSI.

**Question 2**: Don't attempt to write application settings files under the Program Files directory. Instead put them in `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` – see [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

You really should try to get out of the habit of expecting to write to the Program Files directory at any time other than install time. That's why the system provides the various other [special folder locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: OK I get what you are saying, but I've been reading for 2 hours now and still don't see a way to *implement* your suggestion...  What layer/language is all this taking place at?  I get the feeling it's happening at the SHELL level... I'm trying to access things at the .NET, *System.IO* level...  Have we miscommunicated, or am I WAY undereducated on File I/O procedures???

Comment: @Tinkerer call `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)` to get hold of the location of the common app data folder.